# How do I get the GitLab pipeline for a certain CI_PIPELINE_IID?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a version of my software where I know the CI_PIPELINE_IID of the build. How can I find out which pipeline run did that build?

It seems the pipeline runs in the GitLab GUI and the URLs to the pipeline log only contain the global CI_PIPELINE_ID. Is there a way to map from CI_PIPELINE_IID to CI_PIPELINE_ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipeline IID is only significant in the context of a specific project.  The pipeline IID alone, absent of the project information, cannot be used to obtain the global pipeline ID. If you know the project *and* the pipeline IID, it's possible to obtain the global pipeline ID.

However, there is no API operation to obtain a pipeline by its IID. You have to use the [list project pipelines API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines) which will contain both the IID and ID for each pipeline. You can use that response data to build a full map.